# Is it possible to always ask user even if already connected using Facebook Javascript SDK

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login, facebook-graph-api-v2.2

I have MVC5 project written in C# and I use Facebook Javascript SDK, I'm wondering if it's possible to always ask user when login using Facebook.

Example scenario:

User A login to my site using Facebook, and he doesn't logout. His session expired from my site but his Facebook will still logged in. User B using same computer to login using Facebook, since user A didn't logout his Facebook, user B will automatically logged in with User A Facebook account, I need something like "Is this your Facebook account?" prompt before letting user login. Is this provided by Facebook? I'm looking around but no luck so far, and 'FB.login' can't be call after 'response.status' is already 'connected'.

my code :

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                $('#btnFBlogin').click(function () {
                    FB.api('/me', function (response) {

                    location.href = BASE_URL + 'Membership/LogInWithFacebook';
                });
            })
        } else {
            $('#btnFBlogin').click(function () {
                FB.login(function (response) {
                    if (response.status === 'connected') {
                        FB.api('/me', function (response) {
                            location.href = BASE_URL + 'Membership/LogInWithFacebook';
                        });
                    }
                }, { scope: 'email,user_birthday' });
            })
        }
    });
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: But what if the same user tries to login again? He needs to input the credentials again?

Comment: If users share their computer without logging out of certain services, then that’s basically their problem.

Answer (score 0):

The flow should be like this:

1. You should have a customized login button (not the default fb-login button), not sure but I guess you are using the customised button only.
2. On its click, check if the user is already connected using `FB.getLoginStatus()`.
3. If yes, logout the user from facebook using `FB.logout()` and then login the user using `FB.login()`
4. If not, login the user using `FB.login()`.

---

**Code**

```
$('#btnFBlogin').click(function () {
     FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
          if (response.status === 'connected') {
              FB.logout(function(response) {
                 Login();
              });
          }else{
              Login();
          }
     });
});

function Login(){
    FB.login(function (response) {
       if (response.status === 'connected') {
          FB.api('/me', function (response) {
             location.href = BASE_URL + 'Membership/LogInWithFacebook';
          });
       }
    }, { scope: 'email,user_birthday' });
}
```